# Get updated IndexPath for visible item after UICollectionView has scrolled

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView with different periods (day to year) for user to choose. Each item's size is equal to the size of collectionView itself.

```
@IBOutlet weak var periodCollectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var itemLabel: UILabel!

let collectionValues = ["Day", "Week", "Month", "Year"]
var currentVisibleItem: Int?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PeriodName", for: indexPath) as? DisplayPeriodCollectionViewCell
    else {
        fatalError("Unable to cast collection view cell as DisplayPeriodCollectionViewCell")
    }

    cell.periodName.text = collectionValues[indexPath.item]

    return cell

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let height = collectionView.frame.height
    let width = collectionView.frame.width

    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}
```

What i am trying to do is get an info label to display the index of current visible item after collectionView has scrolled. Her is the code:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: periodCollectionView.center.x + periodCollectionView.contentOffset.x, y: 1.0)
    print("centerPoint: \(centerPoint)")

    if let currentItemIndexPath = periodCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: centerPoint) {
        currentVisibleItem = currentItemIndexPath.item
        print("index of current item: \(currentVisibleItem!)")
        itemLabel.text = "\(currentVisibleItem!)"
    } else {
        print("could not get index of current item...")
    }

}
```

I've added print statements to check if values are defined correctly at runtime, and they show everything is fine. The problem is that label does not always update its text after scrolling ends, but instead waits for new scrolling to occur:

[image]

I can't figure out why this is happening - setting a breakpoint at `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` shows that all code gets executed, so what's wrong with the label text?

**UPD**. Not-updating label text appears to be a Simulator issue - when running on device, label updates correctly.

Comment: Does `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_:)` work better?

Comment: I wouldn't rely on something just being a simulator issue.  It might just be a timing thing and you're just not seeing it on your device but it could happen on slower/faster devices.

Comment: The thing is that all the code gets executed every time collection view scrolls - including label update. I checked it with a breakpoint. But on simulator the label update doesn’t show for some reason.

Comment: I've seen issues with updating a label in a scrollView that is scrolling before.  I'm wondering if the scroll animation isn't quite done yet on the simulator but has completed on the device by the time you try to update the label.  Did you try `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation`?

Comment: `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation` doesn't work at all - neither in console (print statements), nor in simulator.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
override func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let currentIndex = scrollView.contentOffset.x / CGFloat((itemWidth + interitemSpacing / 2))
    print(currentIndex)
}
```

Comment: This is a much more compact way to get the index, thanks for the hint! About the label text update - appears to be Simulator issue, check update to question

Answer (score 1):

> Please try the following code.
>
> I used this many times in my real projects and this works fine.

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    
    let visibleIndex = Int(targetContentOffset.pointee.x / collectionView.frame.width)
    print(visibleIndex)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

because each item is at the same size as your collection view.
if you still want to use scroll view delegate you should write your page calculation in the following delegate functions:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(UIScrollView, willDecelerate: Bool)

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(UIScrollView)

func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(UIScrollView)
```

Comment: Problem with `cellForItemAt` method is that it's pretty unpredictable regarding indexPath of current item. When scrolling forward, it gets called twice - for the upcoming cell and the one after it. When scrolling back, it may not get called at all because the cell is still in the stack.

Comment: Did you try to use 
func tableView(UITableView, willDisplay: UITableViewCell, forRowAt: IndexPath)?

Comment: Implementing all three scroll view delegate methods does help to power the arrow buttons seen on gif. They are supposed to iterate through collection items, but single `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating ` method didn't work for them.

Comment: `willDisplay ` gives same unpredictable results - meaning it may return not current cell, but the one after or before it, depending on direction of scroll. For precise calculation of current index the best way is one offered @DenisLitvin in the answer below.